# How do i run Django and phpmyadmin on apache webserver on ubuntu

Tags: django, apache, apache2, phpmyadmin

How do i run Django and phpmyadmin on apache webserver. I used localhost/phpmyadmin and it worked but after i configured Django on localhost/admin, phpmyadmin is not working i get an error page from Django saying the URL is not in urls.py. is there a way to run Django on port 81(httpd.conf) so that it will not conflict with phpmyadmin, or is there something else i am missing.I use mod_python module.This is my httpd.conf file when i change the location "/" to location "/home/projects/" Phpmyadmin works but Django fails and viceversa

```
<location "/">
 SetHandler python-program
 PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
 SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE hana.settings
 PythonPath "['/home/projects/', '/home/projects/mysite', '/home/projects/mysite/mysite'] + sys.path"
</location>
<location "/admin-media">
SetHandler None
</location>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run them both on same port. Just add these lines to your apache config after `WSGIAlias` directive:

```
Alias /phphmyadmin /sys/path/to/phpmyadmin
<Location /phphmyadmin>
SetHandler None
</Location>
```

You can also run them on different ports.

```
Listen 80
Listen 81
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:81

<VirtualHost *:81>
django-config
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
phph-my-admin-configs
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I use mod_python and i dont create a virtual dir for Django. i just added an entry in appache2's httpd.conf

Comment: To handle this i created seperate sites for phpmyadmin and django http://localhost/phpmyadmin  and http://django/admin