# Django urls.py catches all existing HTML projects' urls on WampServer

Tags: django, apache, wamp, django-urls, httpd.conf

I had WampServer working perfectly with Aptana IDE using multiple folders for different html projects. Then I installed Django and added this to Apache's httpd.conf:

```
Alias /images/ "c:/wamp/www/daas/templates/images/"
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/daas/images>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / "c:/wamp/www/daas/apache/django.wsgi"

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/daas/apache">
Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www/daas/
</VirtualHost>
```

and now the virtual hosts I had for html projects...

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot 'C:\wamp\www'
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName projectA.local
    DocumentRoot 'C:\wamp\www\projectA'
</VirtualHost>
```

don't load correctly because Django's urls.py is catching all urls `The current URL, projectA, didn't match any of these regular expressions`, even the ones not inside the Django's projects.

How can I solve this? On Djano's side or on Apache's side? Here ([How do i run Django and phpmyadmin on apache webserver on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5264811/675577)) is a similar problem but the solution didn't worked for me. And luckily `localhost/phpmyadmin` works correctly but `localhost/projectA` doesn't.

Comment: It looks like `WSGIScriptAlias / "c:/wamp/www/daas/apache/django.wsgi"` in your httpd.conf catches all requests on apache. You should try to configure this in your virtualhost settings.

Comment: You were right! I just commented that line using `#` and now previous wamp projects are working again! When I want to use django I just uncomment that line. I can live with that :P Can you post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as best answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `WSGIScriptAlias / "c:/wamp/www/daas/apache/django.wsgi"` in your httpd.conf catches all requests on apache.